# Как выровнять по средине и сделать длиной по самому широкому? ответы по длине могут менятся

Tags: css, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выровнять по средине и  сделать длиной по самому широкому? ответы по длине могут менятся надо чтоб были по серединевведите сюда описание изображения и на экрана и на одной линии по центру [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: должно по дли быть width как max-content и по средине как маргин ауто ?

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов несколько. Например сам список UL размещается во flex-сетке, примерно по такой схеме:

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="flex-grow1"></div> --- пустая ячейка для отступа

    <div class="flex-grow5">
        <ul>
        --- сам список
        </ul>  
    </div>

    <div class="flex-grow1"></div> --- пустая ячейка для отступа
</div>
```

Чтобы не задавать явно ширину используется grow-свойство.